# How to pass child object in the method

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I am parsing the child object to a method but my child data is lost. Please tell how to parse the object without loosing its data.

```
class A
{
  int size;    
  std::string name;
public:    
  A(const std::string &name, int &size){}    
  virtual B *C();
}

function D()
{
  int size = 10;
  std::string name = "name";
  return new A(name , size);
}
B *A::C(){
  \\here I need name and size
}
```

Write now the value of size it give is 0 instead of 10 and for name it give segmentation fault

Thanks 4 the help in advance

**UPDATE 1
the abstract of my code**

```
class PrototypeAST 
{
int size;
std::string FnName;
std::vector<std::string> ArgNames;
public:
PrototypeAST(const std::string &fnName, const std::vector<std::string> &argNames, int &size)
: FnName(fnName), ArgNames(argNames) {}
Function *Codegen();
void CreateArgumentAllocas(Function *F);
};

static PrototypeAST *ParsePrototype() {
  int size;
  std::string FnName = IdentifierStr;
  getNextToken();//eat id1
  std::vector<std::string> ArgNames;
  if(CurTok != ')' )
  {
getNextToken(); //eat int
    ArgNames.push_back(IdentifierStr);
    getNextToken();// eat id
    while (CurTok == ',')
    {
      getNextToken(); //eat ,
      getNextToken(); //eat int
      ArgNames.push_back(IdentifierStr);
      getNextToken();// eat id

    }
  }

  // success.
 getNextToken();  // eat ')'.
 size = ArgNames.size();
 return new PrototypeAST(FnName, ArgNames, size);
}

Function *PrototypeAST::Codegen() {

  printf("\nI am in prototypeAST function\n");

  // Make the function type:  double(double,double) etc.
  std::vector<Type*> Doubles(size,
                         Type::getInt1Ty(getGlobalContext()));
printf("\nI am in prototypeAST function's 1\n");
FunctionType *FT;
if(isFunInt)
  FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt1Ty(getGlobalContext()),
                                   Doubles, false);
    else if(isFunVoid)
     FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt1Ty(getGlobalContext()),
                                   Doubles, false);
          printf("\nI am in prototypeAST function's 2\n");

Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, FnName, TheModule);
printf("\nI am in prototypeAST function's 3\n");
// If F conflicted, there was already something named 'Name'.  If it has a
// body, don't allow redefinition or reextern.
if (F->getName() != FnName) {
  // Delete the one we just made and get the existing one.
  F->eraseFromParent();
  F = TheModule->getFunction(FnName);
  }
// Set names for all arguments.
unsigned Idx = 0;
for (Function::arg_iterator AI = F->arg_begin(); Idx != ArgNames.size();
   ++AI, ++Idx) {
  AI->setName(ArgNames[Idx]);
}
printf("\nI am in prototypeAST function\n");
return F; 
}
```

Comment: Could you post something closer to real C++ code?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: If you really have an empty constructor, I suggest you start looking for the problem there. Remember that giving things the same name doesn't make them the same thing.

Comment: My code is like this only, but I do not think that the empty constructor is the problem. But if it is can you suggest something similar to this code.

Comment: @juanchopanza I have added the update which is the part of real C++ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got what you wanna do. Here is the way to do it.

The empty constructor was making the problem. You can initialize your parameter with the value return by the function in following manner.

```
class A
{
  int Size;    
  std::string Name;
public:    
  A(const std::string &name, int &size):Name(name), Size(size) {}    
  virtual B *C();
}

A *D()
{
  int size = 10;
  std::string name = "name";
  return new A(name , size);
}
B *A::C(){
  \\here I need name and size
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should have looked at the empty constructor. You are not setting the values of the data members in the constructor. That is why the error.

PS: Do familiarize with Stack Overflow question checklist.  Happy learning.

Comment: here is one more question what `function D()` which is actually `function A *D()` will return will it be not be reflected in my constructor class..???

Comment: The thing which I am trying to do is done same at the [llvm tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html) in the same way. But I am getting the error.